# Regex for parsing comment variables in PHP

Tags: php, regex, variables, comments

I have a comment block that can look like this;

```
/**
 * variable1: value
 * variable2: value
 */
```

or like this;

```
/*
variable1: value
variable2: value
*/
```

What I need is to be able to match any number of variable/value pairs and add them to an array. I can't seem to figure it out though, I keep matching the wrong things.

All variables would be single-line, so that should simplify things a little. Spaces before 'variable' or after the the colon should be disregarded, but any other spaces in the value lines should be retained.

UPDATE:

What I ended up going with was a slight expansion of the selected answer;

```
/(\w)*\s*:\s*([\w'"\/.: ]*)/
```

It allowed for URLs to be used as values like so;

```
/**
 * url: 'some/file.png'
 * url: "http://www.google.ca/intl/en_ca/images/logo.gif"
 */
```

Comment: Can you post the regex you tried to get the wrong results? Maybe you aren't too far off.

Comment: Can we assume that we can start with a string $s that contains exactly one comment block and no other data?

Comment: Should your two examples be treat the same?

Comment: I was way off. I couldn't figure out how to match the variables at all, so I was try to match all / or * characters and remove them from the output, then run the output line by line through explode on : and trim start and end spaces from each variable name and value.

Comment: Yes, I can remove everything except the comment block with explode, if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work? (Assuming multi-line matching enabled)

```
(\w)*\s*:\s*(\w*)
```

I assume you pulled off the comment block with something like

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
```

with `.` set to match anything.

Comment: That sort of works. It matches the whole variable line, without splitting out the name and value. Is it possible to split it to key/value pairs in one regex, or would it need another pass? Also the value needs to support spaces, so \w* doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$str=<<<A
/**
 * variable1: value
 * variable2: value
 */

some text

/*
variable1: value
variable2: value
*/

A;

preg_match("/\/\*(.*?)\*\//sm",$str,$matches);
foreach($matches as $k=>$v){
    $v = preg_replace("/\/|\*/sm","",$v);
    $v = array_filter(explode("\n",$v));
    print_r($v);
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [1] =>   variable1: value
    [2] =>   variable2: value
    [3] =>
)
Array
(
    [1] => variable1: value
    [2] => variable2: value
)
```

now you can separate those variables using explode etc..